# Scrolling issue in UITableView with the UIView in it

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

At first I've added to my `Storyboard` an `UITableView`, later inside of it I've added `UIView`

[image]

Now after running my app when I'm trying to scroll my tableView by dragging `UIView` to top(touching on `UIView` and trying to scroll) - it does not scroll, but when I scroll by dragging from tableView - it scrolls.

[image]

How can I fix it and scroll by touching and scrolling over those `UIView`?

Comment: Ideally it should work. Is your profile view is custom view? If yes share your custom view code.

Comment: @ArunAmmannaya no, it's not a custom one. A simple uiview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have checked 'cancellable content touches' of UITableview as below

[image]